# Conjugation and generators

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $x\in G$ be of order $4$. So $o(x)=4$. Suppose that all cyclic subgroups of $G$ of order 4 are conjugate. Show that there exists an involution $g\in G$ such that $\langle x,g\rangle=G$. Further, $x$ is not conjugate to $x^{-1}$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

You can even consider $G$  as Suzuki group $Sz(q)$. The group whose order is $q^2 (q^2 +1)(q−1)$ and $q=2^m$   which $m$  is odd. Also, any two Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$ have trivial intersection.

Comment: What do you mean by "involution $g\in G$"?

Comment: An element of order 2. o(g)=2.

Comment: You should check the question again. It doesn't make much sense at the moment, and your example does not satisfy the hypothesis that all cyclic subgroups of order 4 are conjugate.

Comment: We can consider $G$ as Suzuki group $Sz(q)$. The group whose order is $q^2(q^2+1)(q-1)$ and $q=2^m$ which $m$ is odd. Also, any two Sylow 2-subgroups of G have trivial intersection. Can it be useful?

Comment: Sorry, I gave a wrong example.

Comment: I am sorry, but your new paragraph makes no sense at all. You consider examples when you are trying to prove that something is false, not when you are trying to prove it true. If you are actually asking a specific question about the Suzuki groups, then you should edit the whole post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G={\rm SL}_2(3)$ of order $48$ has three cyclic subgroups of order $4$, which are all conjugate in $G$. But $G$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup of order $8$, so $G$ cannot be generated by an element of order $4$ and an element of order $2$. Furthermore, if $x$ has order $4$ then $x$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}$ in $G$ (and hence also in ${\rm Aut}(G))$.

So something is badly wrong with this exercise!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand if the final sentence "Further, $x$ is not conjugate to $x^{−1}$ in $Aut(G)$ is an hypothesis or a conclusion.

But $G = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has a lot of cyclic subgroups of order $4$; which are not conjugate since $G$ is abelian. And there don't exist elements $x$ and $g$ of order $4$ and $2$ such that $<x,g> = G$.

Edit: Sorry, I don't know why I gave this example where subgroups of order $4$ are NOT conjugate...

Comment: Sorry, I gave a wrong example.

Comment: The final sentence is a conclusion.